# sinch video call camera permission problem with Android pei (9)

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, sinch

**update**

I am developing a small app which requires camera permission. I can handle the run time permission but the real problem is that when I relay to `Sinchpayload` and go to incomming call activity. This activity should request permissions (camera and other 2 permissions). But instead of showing the permission dialogue, it crash my app because of security exception. **this thing happen only if I request camera permission - not happen to other permissions and only on Android 9 with camera "2" Api - Android 8.1 and lower works fine** . **THIS PROBLEM STILL HAPPEN WITH THE SINCH SAMPLE PUSH**. The permission dialogue will show if start activity with intent as usual. This is the error :

```
-------- beginning of crash
2019-02-10 22:11:55.390 2113-2681/com.example.myapp.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: VideoCapturerThread
   Process: com.example.myapp.app, PID: 2113
   java.lang.SecurityException: validateClientPermissionsLocked:1054: Caller "com.example.myapp.app" (PID 10319, UID 2113) cannot open camera "1" without camera permission
       at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:747)
       at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:405)
       at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraForUid(CameraManager.java:567)
       at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCamera(CameraManager.java:495)
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Session.openCamera(Unknown Source:44)
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Session.start(Unknown Source:60)
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Session.<init>(Unknown Source:73)
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Session.create(Unknown Source:17)
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Capturer.createCameraSession(Unknown Source:17)
       at org.webrtc.CameraCapturer$5.run(Unknown Source:52)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
    Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: validateClientPermissionsLocked:1054: Caller "com.example.myapp.app" (PID 10319, UID 2113) cannot open camera "1" without camera permission (code 1)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1967)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
       at android.hardware.ICameraService$Stub$Proxy.connectDevice(ICameraService.java:343)
       at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:369)
       at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraForUid(CameraManager.java:567) 
       at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCamera(CameraManager.java:495) 
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Session.openCamera(Unknown Source:44) 
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Session.start(Unknown Source:60) 
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Session.<init>(Unknown Source:73) 
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Session.create(Unknown Source:17) 
       at org.webrtc.Camera2Capturer.createCameraSession(Unknown Source:17) 
       at org.webrtc.CameraCapturer$5.run(Unknown Source:52) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)`
```

and this is my code to request permissions :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23)
    {
 if (GlobalConstants.isAllPermissionsGrantedBefore_Video_Call(this)==false)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    Video_incomming_call.this,
                   GlobalConstants.mPermissions_Video_Chat,
                    GlobalConstants.VIDEO_RECIEVE_CODE);
        else {
            Start_Calling();
        }

    } else Start_Calling();
```

Comment: Please post related code, where exactly you got error.

Comment: I am using my phone when write this post. I will post my code tomorow. Thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

The app permission dialog only shows in foreground.

Comment: But i started the activity. And i requested the permissions inside the activity, not in background. Thanks

Comment: Btw, note that it only happen on android 9, android 8 works fine